# How to delete a leased blob in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-eventhub, dapr

I am publishing and subscribing to azure event hub, which uses blob in the container in a storage account. Messages are not published with this storage account but working with another storage account.

I could see the blob with the lease status as **leased**. I think deleting it and creating it again may solve the issue, so I tried to delete this and create a new one. But not able to delete it. I also tried breaking the lease but it again sets the lease status to leased.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you check the Blob Property Overview please. What are the values of:
LEASE STATUS, LEASE STATE, LEASE DURATION. 

Normally, the person who requested a lease must release it by Lease ID. If a break is requested for a lease, this cannot actually be leased again directly. With a break, a cool down is set.

Comment: Lease status is **locked**, lease state is **leased** and lease duration is **fixed** @Sven

Comment: Do you know which process/service is acquiring the lease even after you broker it?

Comment: I don’t know. Is there any way to know this? @GauravMantri

Comment: Enable Diagnostic Settings for this container. Then break the lease and after that check the logs. I would guess that you need to disconnect the Event Hub from the Storage. I assume that this service has access to your blob.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. One possible solution would be to break the lease and immediately acquire the lease (note down the lease id). You can use that lease id when deleting the blob.

Comment: @GauravMantri tried breaking lease and deleting. But it gets the lease again. So can’t delete again

Comment: That's why I said that you should try to acquire the lease yourself instead of some other process acquire the lease. That way the other process cannot lock the blob and using the lease id you will be able to delete the blob. You'll need to write some code to do so.

Comment: @GauravMantri but in that case other service will face the same issue, if my service acquires lock. Is there any way so that multiple services can publish on the same storage container?

Comment: I thought you wanted to delete the blob. There's only one client that can acquire a lock on a blob at any given point of time.

Comment: @GauravMantri I got the other service which has locked the blob. But I am facing one weird issue. If the blob is in the leased state, other services are not able to publish and subscribe using this storage account. But I don't know why

Comment: @Sven please check the above comment

Comment: That blob appears to be related to partition ownership emitted by an event processor client.  To delete it, you'd need to stop the processors consuming events that are configured to use that storage account.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the underlying issue that you're trying to solve is?  Deleting these blobs will only reset consumer state for the processors reading events.   It would cause your partition ownership to rebalance on restart and potentially reset to reading the beginning of each partition event stream - but it sounds like you're trying to solve something for publishing...

Comment: @JesseSquire this is the real issue I’m facing https://stackoverflow.com/q/70651840/6527049

Comment: I can't speak to Dapr, unfortunately, only to the Event Hubs SDK itself which is used by the Dapr components.  That said, if you've got two subscribers using the same storage account, they will collaborate using storage and share partitions between them - you won't have two independent consumers running.  To do that, you'll need a separate storage container AND consumer group for the second consumer.

Comment: @JesseSquire I have tried using different containers within the same storage account. That’s also not working.

Comment: That definitely sounds like Dapr is doing something with storage, then.   The SDK itself only cares about the container.

Comment: @JesseSquire I have added **dapr** tag in the question. I have also raised bug here https://github.com/dapr/dapr/issues/4112. Thanks a lot for your time and help. Your comments were really helpful.

Comment: @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT done, sorry for the late response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   I tried to reproduce your exact scenario by creating a blob container and uploading a blob in it. Then acquiring it on lease through REST API, breaking the lease and then finally deleting the blob through REST API itself all successfully. I used ‘Postman’ application as the REST API platform for this purpose and also used an application registered in Azure AD through which the token required for the blob operations to be performed was retrieved. Please find the below snapshots for your reference: -

a)  Blob ‘ACMx7.pdf’ acquired on lease through appropriate blob owner and user authorization and header parameters.

[image: Postman blob create]
[image: Azure Blob create]

b)  Blob ‘ACMx7.pdf’ lease has been broken through appropriate header, i.e., x-ms-lease-action : break

[image: Postman blob break]
[image: Azure Blob break]

c)  Blob ‘ACMx7.pdf’ has been deleted after the lease has been broken by passing the headers in ‘Postman’ as below.

[image: Postman blob delete]
[image: Azure Blob delete]

Please note that the lease given to the blob was given for an infinite period with reference from the below documentation links on using the required headers for the action required on the blob: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-blob